# windows 7 domain computer unable to change keyboard input method

Tags: windows-7, windows, language, windows-domain, layout

I have 16 Dell latitude E6420, all with same image of Windows 7 Ultimate and joined to the same local domain network.Now, I've tried setting Chinese as default input language, setting Chinese as display language, checked for the Chinese (Simplified) language pack install.Except for 1 Windows 10 domain laptop, the rest are all unable to change language.No any language bar was displayed, and <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> didn't switch the language too.Only at the login screen user can switch language, and the language bar was showed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I had disabled that ctfmon.exe at startup so it was unable to switch between languages. Re-enabled it by gpo adding reg key in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`,regkey type REG_SZ with value `'%windir\System32\ctfmon.exe'`